# munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer while freeing a struct in an array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

So I wrote a program where I have to realloc an array of structs whenever I want to add something to it.
But when I try to free the array, I free every element individually but I get a `munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer` at some point.

Here is the full code :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Date {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};

struct Person {
    char *name;
    char *surname;
    struct Date birth;
};

struct Directory {
    int size;
    struct Person *array;
};

struct Date create_date() {
    struct Date date = {
            .day = 0,
            .month = 0,
            .year = 0
    };

    return date;
}

struct Directory create_directory() {
    struct Directory directory = {
            .size = 0,
            .array = NULL
    };

    return directory;
}

struct Person *create_person() {
    struct Person *person_ptr = (struct Person *) malloc(sizeof(struct Person));

    person_ptr->name = NULL;
    person_ptr->surname = NULL;

    return person_ptr;
}

void copy_date(struct Date *dest, struct Date *src) {
    dest->day = src->day;
    dest->month = src->month;
    dest->year = src->year;
}

void initialize_person(struct Person *person_ptr, char *name, char *surname, struct Date *birth) {
    if (name != NULL && surname != NULL && birth != NULL) {
        person_ptr->name = realloc((*person_ptr).name, (strlen(name) * sizeof(char)) + 1);
        strcpy(person_ptr->name, name);

        person_ptr->surname = realloc((*person_ptr).surname, (strlen(surname) * sizeof(char)) + 1);
        strcpy(person_ptr->surname, surname);

        copy_date(&person_ptr->birth, birth);
    }
}

void copy_person(struct Person *dest, struct Person *src) {
    dest->name = realloc((*dest).name, (strlen(src->name) * sizeof(char)) + 1);
    dest->surname = realloc((*dest).surname, (strlen(src->surname) * sizeof(char)) + 1);

    struct Date date = create_date();
    dest->birth = date;

    strcpy(dest->name, src->name);
    strcpy(dest->surname, src->surname);
    copy_date(&dest->birth, &src->birth);
}

int add_person(struct Directory *directory_ptr, const struct Person *new_person_ptr) {
    int return_code = 0;

    directory_ptr->size++;
    directory_ptr->array = realloc(directory_ptr->array, (directory_ptr->size * sizeof(struct Person)));

    if (directory_ptr->array) {
        copy_person(&directory_ptr->array[directory_ptr->size - 1], (struct Person *) new_person_ptr);
    } else {
        return_code = 1;
    }

    return return_code;
}

int add_multiple_persons(struct Directory *directory_ptr, const struct Person **persons_ptr, int nb_persons) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nb_persons; i++) {
        add_person(directory_ptr, (persons_ptr[i]));
    }

    return 0;
}

void destroy_person(struct Person *person_ptr) {
    free(person_ptr->name);
    person_ptr->name = NULL;

    free(person_ptr->surname);
    person_ptr->surname = NULL;

    free(person_ptr);
    person_ptr = NULL;
}

void destroy_directory(struct Directory *directory_ptr) {
    if (directory_ptr->array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < directory_ptr->size; i++) {
            destroy_person(&directory_ptr->array[i]);
        }
        directory_ptr->array = NULL;
        directory_ptr->size = 0;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    struct Directory directory = create_directory();
    struct Person *person1 = create_person();
    struct Person *person2 = create_person();
    struct Person *person3 = create_person();
    struct Date date = {
            .day = 17,
            .month = 04,
            .year = 1999};

    initialize_person(person1, "Marcel", "Juan", &date);
    initialize_person(person2, "Albin", "Michel", &date);
    initialize_person(person3, "Suzerain", "Bernard", &date);

    const struct Person *array[] = {
            person1,
            person2,
            person3
    };

    add_multiple_persons(&directory, array, 3);
    destroy_person(person1);
    destroy_person(person2);
    destroy_person(person3);
    destroy_directory(&directory);

    return 0;
}
```

I've been on this error for more than a week, and it keeps bugging me.
How can I fix this ?

Comment: Could you please clarify after which line execution does the error appears?

Comment: The error occurs on line 109, after the call to destroy_person() from destroy_directory()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the destroy_directory function, you freed the persons contained by the array. But in this array you didn't put pointers to structures but the structures themselves. Therefore you must free the space you allocated for the array and nothing else :

```
    void destroy_directory(struct Directory *directory_ptr) {
       if (directory_ptr->array) {

           free(directory_ptr->array); //<==== Here

           directory_ptr->array = NULL;
           directory_ptr->size = 0;
       }
    }
```

Comment: `You cannot use realloc with a string that was not allocated via malloc. So in the initialization function you should use malloc instead of realloc`. This is not true. If the first argument is `NULL`, `realloc` behaves exactly the same as `malloc`.

Comment: @emi You're right I thought that the OP passed the literal string declared in main in realloc but it didn't. Thanks for pointing that.

Comment: Upvoted after edit: it's clearer than mine. @dspr It is NULLified in `create_person` during initial declaration.

Answer (score 0):

`person_ptr` is a part of the memory allocated at `directory_ptr->array`. You need to remove this line.

As a rule of gold, memory responsible is the same while allocation and while freeing. In your code, the `person` holder is the `array` inside `directory_ptr`, which is allocated by `add_person`. Despite its name, it is a `directory` manager, so freeing its memory should be done only on `directory` destroyer.